# HIGHS_CMD configured in Pulp. Sometime the solver stucks while writing the solution to file

Tags: linear-programming, solver, pulp, highs

I have a MIP problem in PULP. I set HIGHS_CMD as solver. Everything works fine but sometime (I cannot understand when it happens) the solver, when it solves the problem, it stucks with the writing: "Writing the solution to *****.sol".
It seems something like permission on the file but a lot of time it can proceed without any issue also with the same input data.
I cannot undesrtand why sometime it freezes at the end.
Is there any with the same problem?

I tried to set log file directory but nothing.